# How to compare two identically sized images in python, replacing pixels that match between the two images with black pixels

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have two images for example

```
import numpy as np

img1 = np.array([[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],[[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]])
img2 = np.array([[[1,1,1],[1,1,1]],[[3,3,3],[1,1,1]]])
```

I'd like to compare the two and, where the pixels are matching, and where they don't match, use the pixels from img1, and where they do match, replace the pixels with black pixels

desired result:

```
[[[0,0,0],[2,2,2]],[[0,0,0],[4,4,4]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.all(-1)` on `img1==img2` to check for equality on all channels. Then `np.where` with broadcasting:

```
out = np.where((img1==img2).all(axis=-1)[...,None], (0,0,0), img1)
```

**Or**, since you are masking with `(0,0,0)`, you can use `.any(axis=-1)` on `img1!=img2` to detect difference on some channel, then broadcast and multiply:

```
out = (img1!=img2).any(axis=-1)[...,None] * img1
```

Output:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [4, 4, 4]]])
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.

One thing I'm not sure of, is what the [...,None] does

Comment: @db9 have a look at [the documentations](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:~:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how%20numpy%20treats%20arrays,that%20looping%20occurs%20in%20C%20instead%20of%20Python.)